# How to deal with this sequence alignement problem?

Tags: time-series, deep-learning, lstm, sequential-pattern-mining

Assume the following input sequences.

```
___JJJJIII___I____OOO0O______HHHHHH_____MMNNN___
AAAAAI_NNNNNNNNNNNA_AAAA_
___MMMM______A______RR_I______KK_
```

which corresponds to the following labels:

```
JOHN
ANNA
MARK
```

How can I build a model that can learn to 'translate' those sequences into the right labels.

I've though that a sequence to sequence recurrent network will be able to do this, but the generated sequence I got is nearly random.

I've also tried a [Connectionist Temporal Classification](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/icml_2006.pdf) which seems to do exactly what I want.

[image]

But [the implementation I've tried](https://github.com/sherjilozair/ctc) returns me an empty strings

Any working exemple for the previously cited methods ?
Any suggestion of an other method to solve this problem ?

### Edit:

seq2seq RNN is rendering something coherent when working (training and testing) with constant length sequences only. (I already tried to pad the other sequences to get the same length ... same thing)

Comment: `But the implementation I've tried returns me an empty strings` Did you try to study the trouble? For example, start with the documented example, then make the input data a little bit more compex and a bit closer to your data, then a bit further... Until you find what causes the no result.

Comment: I ran the provided [rnnctc.py](https://github.com/sherjilozair/ctc/blob/master/examples/rnnctc.py) exemple and it also generate empty strings in the beginning. After 10k iterations it learned that he must choose every 4 letters of the input as the output.
I've strings with multiple lengths, and multiple spacing, that's why he learned nothing I think.